# HTML source indentation for ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

When you add some code to a ckeditor in HTML view and then change to WYSIWYG view and come back, almost all HTML tags have been modified and have loose the indentation. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? (parameter, plugin, hard code...)

For example:

```
<div class="former input">
    <span class="big horizontal">
        <label for="test">Hi world</label>
        <input class="medium free" id="test" name="test" type="text" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="former input">
    <span class="big horizontal"><label for="test">Hi world</label><input class="medium free" id="test" name="test" type="text" /></span></div>
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, can you post a sample of the code you enter in source (HTML) mode as well as the modified code that is generated when you switch to WYSIWYG mode and then back to source mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to a page in the developer's guide:
[Output Formatting](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting)

It explains how to control the layout of the HTML code that is output by the editor and has an example that sets the formatting for the `<p>` tag.

Try using the `<p>` tag example as a template and set the formatting for the `<span>`, `<label>` and `<input>` tags using the same approach.

```
writer.setRules( 'span',
writer.setRules( 'label',
writer.setRules( 'input',
```

Be Well,
Joe