# CKEditor: Keep source indentation

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm using following config for CKEditor:

```
var wysiwyg = ck.replace(el[0], {
  allowedContent: true,
  protectedSource: [/\r|\n/g]
});
```

I'm loading HTML source into CKEditor as:

```
<div style='font-weight: bold;'> 
  <div> 
    <div> test </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

On `wysiwyg.getData()` I receive:

```
<div style="font-weight: bold;">
<div>
<div>test</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**How can I force CKEditor to keep my indentation as per source?**

I tried to use different regex inside `protectedSource` to protect everything between HTML `>...<` like `/(?:\>)([^<]*?)(?:\<)/g` https://regex101.com/r/eV4dO0/1 but without luck.

Comment: I think this may be helpful http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_output_format. From here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7579569/2321666

Comment: I used the `setRules` feature from http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_output_format but it's not ideal. I would like to keep the source formatting as it is. Is this possible?

Comment: So you don't want to make `<div style='font-weight: bold;'>...</div>` **not** editable in WYSIWYG mode or merely preserve the formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to keep the source formatting as it is. Is this possible?

**No, it isn't**. Content is passed through parsers, filters, writers and browser's DOM many times before it returns to you. You cannot expect to preserve every single tab or space character which is not significant in terms of the content. Please remember that CKEditor is not a code editor - it is a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly,add those two lines for CKeditor to Config file

```
config.protectedSource = [/\r|\n/g];
config.allowedContent = true;
```